# Windows Azure update table rowkey

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm storing an image in the blobstorage and information about that image in the tablestorage. The table rowkey is the image name.
I want to change the image description(rowkey) for the selected item.

```
//string name is the bloburl, string description is the new image description
public ActionResult UpdateImageDescription(string Name, string ImageDescription)
{
    //Get blob url
    Uri bloburi = new Uri(Name);
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(bloburi.LocalPath);

    //Get tabledata and make it a list
    CloudTable table = tableStorageServices.GetCloudTable();
    TableQuery<ImageEntity> query = new TableQuery<ImageEntity>();

    foreach (ImageEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
    {
//find the matching urls
        if (bloburi.ToString() == entity.Url)
        {
            entity.ImageDescription = ImageDescription;
            break;
        }
    }
```

I've debugged the program and i can see that the imagedescription and the new imagedescription is right, but it seems like it's not saving the change.

Thank you for helping me. I'm still a newbie @azure so be patient with me:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write the changes you've made to Azure--which you're not doing.  If you want to merge the changes, you should use the `Merge` operation.  If you intend to replace the entire entity, you can use the `Replace` operation.  To use the `Replace` operation, you can do something like:

```
TableOperation replaceOperation = TableOperation.Replace(entity);
table.Execute(replaceOperation);
```

Comment: Ah thanks that did it. I wish I could vote you up but i dont have the points.

Comment: @user3276084 You can't mark an answer to your own question the answer?